# Locally I am trying to push my docker image to AWS ECR repository but I am getting the below mentioned error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to push my image from local to AWS ECR , but I get the below error in my terminal

> failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `not implemented`

There are bunch of suggestions available on stack overflow or on google , but none of them worked for me .
I am using windows 11 .

Reproducible steps

1. installed docker desktop.
2. locally built an image .
3. created a repository on aws ECR.
4. ran aws configure.
5. Tried this command to push the image

> aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login
> --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/xxxxxxx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please show the command you are running that results in that error. Please provide all the details necessary for someone to replicate the issue.

Comment: Added in the body

Comment: What terminal? bash in linux, powershell in windows? Something else? Your question lacks many relevant details.

Comment: command prompt in windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws
```

For a public registry on ECR you use `us-east-1` region for password.

The principle difference to your original command is that the URI is just `public.ecr.aws` with no `/` or anything after.

[image]

Comment: This yields a password like a token.

Comment: In the original command which i have posted in the description , i removed ecr-login and used only ecr and got this error failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://public.ecr.aws/v2/ failed with status: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Sorry, was not thinking about this being a public registry. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by removing these from my computer

> C:\ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-desktop.exe
> C:\ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe

After that I was able to successfully login (I do see some warning) , but for now it's working . please see the message.

> failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid. WARNING!
> Your password will be stored unencrypted in
> C:\Users\Username.docker\config.json. Configure a credential helper
> to remove this warning. See
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
>
> Login Succeeded

Comment: Also , make sure that you remove the config.josn file from this location C:\Users\UserName\.docker